# How to call a Twig function with the argument being another Twig function or filter?

Tags: php, twig

I've made a Twig Extension with some filters and need to call a function with the argument being another function or a filter but it does not output correctly, the argument gets outputed outside of the function call.

for instance:

```
        {% set clean_url = current_url|NoQuery %}
        {{ BeginPostForm(clean_url) }}
```

or

```
    {{ BeginPostForm(URL()) }}
```

this outputs first the function argument and then the function output as if the default argument was passed. ( ie : /blog/welcome  instead of &ltform action='/blog/welcome'&gt )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually in php when passing a function to a function you do something like this: BeginPostForm('URL') if BeginPostForm's deceleration is BeginPostForm($link). Then in BeginPostForm you can call $link();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I was doing echo instead of return on my Twig_Extension functions, that's why it was behaving badly.